# Getting count of each row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Consider below table:

```
EmpId  EmpType ExpUniId
1       A        234
1       B        453
2       A        454
```

I want to write a sql query such that I get following data

```
EmpId  EmpType ExpUniId   Count
1       A        234       2
1       B        453       2
2       A        454       1
```

Count implies number of rows corresponding to each Emp Id

I am using Oracle Sql.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the analytic version of `count()`:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by EmpId) as Count
from table t;
```